# ajax does not work with multipart/form-data in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the below code

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:panel id="panelEmployee">
<h:commandButton value="Go" action="#{employee.getFirstEmployee()}">
<f:ajax render="panelEmployee" execute="@form"/>   
</h:commandButton>
<p:fileUpload value="#{employee.file}" mode="simple" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/> 
</p:panel>
</h:form>
```

When i clicked on go button and if the form enctype is multipart/form-data then the first ajax call is ok, the second one gives this javascript error

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'contentWindow': object is null or undefined
```

Can anyone please suggest?
Thanks.

Comment: What browser? Have you tried it across multiple browsers

Comment: The above error comes in all browsers.